# Mysql change column data type from integer to decimal(3,2) without loosing old data

Tags: mysql

I have a price column with the type of int(10) unsigned, but for some reason, I need to change the type of column to decimal(3,2), how can I do this without losing data stored already with int(10)?

```sql
ALTER TABLE packages MODIFY price  decimal(3,2)
```

but this command changes all value to 9,99 ?

how can i do this with minimum pain?

Comment: Decimal(3,2) means column length is 2 with 2 decimal place - which is fine if the int field your converting from is < 10 (in value)

Comment: integer values less than -9 or greater than 9 will be converted to -9.99 or 9.99 respectively, the minimum and maximum values allowed for `DECIMAL(3,2)`. (the number before the comma is the total number of digits, so this is one digit before the decimal point and two after. maybe you want `DECIMAL(5,2)` (? just a guess) to allow for three digits before the decimal point? With that, for values outside the range of -999 and 999 are still going to get converted to the min/max values allowed. What value did you want to assign to the new datatype for values that are outside the valid range?

Comment: I get the wrong definition of decimal, that's why I choose decimal(3,2). your explanation made me clear, that I have to choose decimal(10,2) because my I need 10 digit number and 2 digits after the decimal point

Comment: @MohamadKarimi That would mean you're bounded by `99,999,999.99 -- decimal(10, 2)`. Or did you need `9,999,999,999.99 -- decimal(12, 2)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your prices probably get floored down to the maximum allowed decimal you've given. Try:

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE statement(IN dynamic_statement TEXT)
BEGIN
      SET @dynamic_statement := dynamic_statement;
      PREPARE prepared_statement FROM @dynamic_statement;
      EXECUTE prepared_statement;
      DEALLOCATE PREPARE prepared_statement;
  END;

DELIMITER ;

SET @var_digit_length :=
(SELECT MAX(CEIL(LOG(10, ABS(price))))
FROM packages)
;

SET @var_precision := 2;

CALL statement(CONCAT('
    ALTER TABLE packages MODIFY price decimal(',
    (@var_digit_length + @var_precision), ',', @var_precision, ');
'));



DROP PROCEDURE statement;
```

Comment: nice. in the more general case of signed (including negative) values, we would want to also check the minimum value  `MAX(CEIL(LOG10( IF(price<0,price*-1,price )))`  or `MAX(CEIL(LOG10( price*SIGN(price) )))` or  `CEIL(LOG10( MAX(ABS(price)) ))`

Comment: @spencer7593 Thanks. I've modified it to take signed values into consideration as well.

Answer (score 1):

Simply convert datat type by this sql scripts if you don't need to backup and/or just want to data type:

/* Convert column data type */

ALTER TABLE PriceTable
MODIFY COLUMN Price_column decimal(3, 2);